# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got an error message when I was trying to build an app that contains chat, the message is:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

a screenshot of the error message:

[image]
my code:

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user2= FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return FutureBuilder(
      // future: Future<String>.delayed(
      //   Duration(seconds: 2),
      //       () => 'Data Loaded',
      // ),
      //future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      builder:(ctx, futureSnapshot){
        if(futureSnapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());}
      return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').orderBy('createdAt',descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot){
        if(chatSnapshot.connectionState== ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }

        if(chatSnapshot.hasData){
        final chatDocs=  chatSnapshot.data.docs;

            return ListView.builder(
              //key: ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID),
            reverse: true,
              itemCount:chatDocs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index)=> MessageBubble(
                  chatDocs[index]['text'],
                  chatDocs[index]['userId'],
                  //chatDocs[index]['userId'] ==futureSnapshot.data.udi,
                ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID),
              )
          );}
        else{
          return Text('عذرًا, هناك مشكلة');
        }
        },
        );
      },

    );
  }
```

Can anyone suggest a solution and tell me what should I do?

Comment: are you sure your error is coming from this part of your code?

Comment: @pedropimont actually I am not sure if the error comes from this class or another class, can I send you my code of another class?

Comment: the source of the error seems to be that you're passing a String to a parameter or to a if statement when in reality it expects a bool

Comment: sure, you can send it

Comment: check datatype of variable MessageBubble .

Comment: @MansiBhatt MessageBubble is a class

Comment: can u please provide that class code

Comment: @MansiBhatt I wrote it as a comment in this question, can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line you commented here:

```
MessageBubble(
 chatDocs[index]['text'],
 chatDocs[index]['userId'],
 // chatDocs[index]['userId'] ==futureSnapshot.data.udi,
 ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID),
)
```

Why? Your Object MessageBubble has 4 positional arguments. The third one of them is `isMe` and expects a `boolean`. However, your passing the ValueKey (since they are positional).

Also, your not providing the 4º argument that is `required` since all positional arguments are `required`

```
 class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
    final String messsage;
    final userID;
    final bool isMe;
    final Key key;
    MessageBubble(this.messsage,this.userID, this.isMe,this.key);
```

You could:

1. Either uncomment this line `chatDocs[index]['userId'] ==futureSnapshot.data.udi` or pass it another boolean value (true or false)

Comment: I was trying some solution to fix this issue so I comment this line, but I have already uncomment it and also there is an error

Comment: when I fix this, another error appears which is (The getter 'udi' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: udi)

Comment: try: futureSnapshot?.data?.udi >> this is a null aware operator and it won't call any method if the value before '?'  is null

Comment: I think it works!, but also another error appears ( Class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docsID'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: docsID) ,,,,, there is a line in my code i got it from my flutter course, i think the error from it ,,,,, the line is (  ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID)   )

Comment: The chatDocs[index] seems to be a QueryDocumentSnapshot that is a class from Firebase and it doesnt have this property docID. you can probably use chatDocs[index].data()['docID'] or chatDocs[index].id . Anyway is hard for me to guess since I dont know that are u retrieving from Firebase

Comment: sorry to bother you, also it works with me, but another error appears when I try to send the message, it still in the box and doesn't disappear ([ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null. )

Comment: again your trying to access the uid property from a object that is null. Make sure that you have a proper Object with this uid property in the variable you're trrying to call it or again use the null aware operator variable?.property

Answer (score 0):

@MansiBhatt

MessageBubble class:

```
 class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
      final String messsage;
      final userID;
      final bool isMe;
      final Key key;
      MessageBubble(this.messsage,this.userID, this.isMe,this.key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: isMe? MainAxisAlignment.start: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isMe? Colors.grey[300]: nave,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                  bottomLeft: !isMe ? Radius.circular(12) : Radius.circular(0),
                  bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(12) : Radius.circular(0),
    
                ),
              ),
              width: 140,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 16),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder(
              

      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).get(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.connectionState== ConnectionState.waiting){
                      return Text('جاري التحميل...');}
                      return Text(snapshot.data['username'], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
                    }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(messsage, style: TextStyle(color: isMe? white : Colors.black,),),
            ],
          ) ,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: u should define  4 values as constructor defined

Comment: u have mentioned 3 only , bool isMe value not defined in thi MessageBubble(
                  chatDocs[index]['text'],
                  chatDocs[index]['userId'],
                  //chatDocs[index]['userId'] ==futureSnapshot.data.udi,
                ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID),
              )

Comment: @MansiBhatt when I fix this, another error appears which is (The getter 'udi' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: udi)

Comment: with this chatDocs[index]['userId'] ==futureSnapshot.data.udi?

Comment: then check whether futureSnapshot .data is null or not

Comment: @MansiBhatt I think it works!, but also another error appears ( Class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docsID'. Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' Tried calling: docsID) ,,,,, there is a line in my code i got it from my flutter course, i think the error from it ,,,,, the line is ( ValueKey(chatDocs[index].docsID) )